# Inverse selection in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 view

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I create a view to select entities which DO NOT HAVE some properties!

For example, I could easily select entities which have phone call activities, but how can I select entities which do not have any phone call activity?

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks it's impossible to create such view inside CRM, only you can select such entities using SSRS.

Comment: Its weird...it should be possible :-/ How can we achieve it using SSRS?

Comment: I'm forced to disagree - it shouldn't be possible.  Views use queries not entirely unlike SQL statements.  You could not achieve this query in a single statement because the join is impossible.  You would need to do (at least) two queries; one subquery to acquire the records you DON'T want and then the outer query to retrieve records which aren't in the subquery.

Comment: But, a right outer join with a filtering statement in where (to strip not null, and so, not needed results) should be possible in SQL.